# How do I solve my problem with 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays

Hey I want do write a program for a friend to manage his trading cards and have a problem with writing that two dimensional Array. [0][0] and [0][1] get saved and processed properly, but in the second iteration of the loop it gives following error code:

```
***Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
at benni/benni.Main.main(Main.java:13)***


package benni;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String[][] inventory = new String[1000][2];     
    for(int i=0;i<999;i++) {    
        try (Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String cn = inp.next(); 
            System.out.println("Cardname: "+cn);
            inventory[i][0]=cn;
            int fq = inp.nextInt();
            String fq2 = Integer.toString(fq);
            inventory[i][1]=fq2;
            System.out.println("Frequency: "+fq2);          
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: do you really want to make a new Scanner 1000 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful about `.nextInt()` because it does not consume the newline character. You should always call `.nextLine()` afterwards to consume the newline.

If you *know* that your input is perfect, this works:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String[][] inventory = new String[1000][2];     

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=0;i<999;i++) {    
            String cn = inp.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println("Cardname: "+cn);
            inventory[i][0]=cn;
            int fq = inp.nextInt();
            inp.nextLine();
            String fq2 = Integer.toString(fq);
            inventory[i][1]=fq2;
            System.out.println("Frequency: "+fq2);          
        }
    }
}
```

However you *should* think about handling your potential `InputMismatchException` when getting your frequency.